# Rust wasm: returning two `Uint8Array`s

Tags: javascript, typescript, rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

When I write a function that returns one `js_sys::Uint8Array` (in Rust):

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub extern "C" fn gen_pubKey(seed: &[u8]) -> Uint8Array {
    let (privKey, pubKey) = ed25519::keypair(&seed);
    unsafe { Uint8Array::view(&pubKey) }
}
```

then compile it using `wasm-pack`, then call the wasm function this way from the js/typescript side:

```
let seed = new Uint8Array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]);
let pubKey: Uint8Array = gen_pubKey(seed);
console.log({ pubKey });
```

The result pubKey is correctly cast to an `Uint8Array` by typescript.

**Now, how can I return two `Uint8Array`s from a rust function and get them to cast to correctly to `Uint8Array` on the typescript side ?**

---

I've tried the following things:

- Putting the two `Uint8Array`s into a struct and returning the struct from `gen_keypair()`

```rust
    #[wasm_bindgen]
    pub struct KeyPairJS {
        pub privKey: Uint8Array,
        pub pubKey: Uint8Array,
    }
```

This doesn't even compile because `js_sys::Uint8Array` doesn't implement `IntoWasmAbi`

- Putting `*const Uint8Array`s into this struct, and returning that from `gen_keypair()`

```rust
    #[wasm_bindgen]
    pub struct KeyPairJS {
        pub privKey: *const Uint8Array,
        pub pubKey: *const Uint8Array,
    }
```

This doesn't work because `*const Uint8Array` is only a number. On the typescript side, it doesn't implement all the methods of `Uint8Array`

- Creating a type that both implements `IntoWasmAbi` and contains enough info to find the `Uint8Array`'s contents in memory, to re-create it from the typescript side:

```rust
    #[wasm_bindgen]
    #[derive(Copy, Clone)]
    pub struct Bytes {
        offset: *const u8,
        size: usize,
    }

    #[wasm_bindgen]
    impl Bytes {
        pub fn new(bytes: &[u8]) -> Bytes {
            Bytes {
                offset: bytes.as_ptr(),
                size: bytes.len(),
            }
        }

        pub fn offset(&self) -> *const u8 {
            self.offset
        }

        pub fn size(&self) -> usize {
            self.size
        }
    }
```

Here I'm not sure how to access the current wasm instance's memory buffer (either [from rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199564/rust-wasm-how-to-access-webassembly-memory-of-current-instance-from-rust) or [from typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60199785/wasm-bindgen-access-wasm-instances-memory-buffer-from-js)), which I would need to re-create the original `Uint8Array`s

- Other things like returning tuples, arrays of `Uint8Array`s, but without any success

Comment: Is the original one return version correct? It seem to return a view into memory of an object that will go out of scope at the end of the function. (I'd have expected a `UInt8Array::new` and no unsafe). But I've not used the wasm stuff, so maybe some magic is going on that I dont know about...

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I do admit it looks wrong to me too, but somehow it works, the js side is able to cast the underlying bytes from memory to a type it owns. And then use it freely and pass it around long after the rust function returned. So it works, I just don't know why.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson so for the update, rust does free the memory on return but the bytes are still present there for the js side to use. Only, that memory is likely to be overwritten at the next js->wasm call (so I found out after it caused me a few headaches). The dirty workaround is to simply copy the bytes on the js side as soon as they are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Wasm Bindgen requires public methods to be Copy. A solution to this is to make the struct fields private and [implement getter/setter methods](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/attributes/on-rust-exports/getter-and-setter.html). Using Box instead of Uint8Array:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub struct KeyPairJS {
    privKey: Box<[u8]>,
    pubKey: Box<[u8]>,
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
impl KeyPairJS {
    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        // Keypair generation here
    }
    #[wasm_bindgen(getter)]
    pub fn privKey(&self) -> Box<[u8]> {
        self.privKey
    }
}
```

You can then access it from javascript as though it is a regular class field.

```js
var keys = new KeyPairJS();
var privateKey = keys.privKey
```